# I am unable to install near-cli with npm from imac terminal

Tags: node.js, npm-install

Can someone help me install `near-cli` on iMac computer with Mojave 10.14.06 using npm

```
$ npm install -g near-cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.near-cli-gSAA3GSK
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.near-cli-gSAA3GSK'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.near-cli-gSAA3GSK'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.near-cli-gSAA3GSK'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: use `sudo` at starting like `sudo npm install -g near-cli`

Comment: If you have to use `sudo` for this installation your node install is broken and you should consider reinstalling node via `brew`. Using `sudo` for npm installs can have all sorts of side effects that may break things